# Replace value on specific column if condition is met

Tags: r, dplyr, replace, conditional-statements, mutate

I have a `wide df` with `columns` representing the `months` of many given `years` and the changes of colour in each `month`:

```
df <- data.frame(id = as.integer(c(123,124,125,126)),
                 change = as.integer(c(0,1,0,1)),
                 change_date = as.character(c(NA, "May.2010", NA, "Sep.2010")),
                 `Jan.2010` = as.character(c("green", "black", "pink", "grey")),
                 `Feb.2010` = as.character(c("green", "black", "pink", "grey")),
                 `Mar.2010` = as.character(c("green", "red", "pink", "grey")),
                 `Apr.2010` = as.character(c("green", "red", "pink", "grey")),
                 `May.2010` = as.character(c("green", "red", "pink", "grey")),
                 `Jun.2010` = as.character(c("green", NA, "pink", "grey")),
                 `Jul.2010` = as.character(c("green", NA, "pink", "grey")),
                 `Ago.2010` = as.character(c("red", NA, "pink", "grey")),
                 `Sep.2010` = as.character(c("red", NA, "pink", "grey")),
                 `Oct.2010` = as.character(c("red", NA, "pink", NA)),
                 `Nov.2010` = as.character(c("red", NA, "pink", NA)),
                 `Dez.2010` = as.character(c("red", NA, "grey", NA))
)
df  

  id change change_date Jan.2010 Feb.2010 Mar.2010 Apr.2010 May.2010 Jun.2010 Jul.2010 Ago.2010 Sep.2010 Oct.2010 Nov.2010 Dez.2010
1 123      0        <NA>    green    green    green    green    green    green    green      red      red      red      red      red
2 124      1    May.2010    black    black      red      red      red     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
3 125      0        <NA>     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     grey
4 126      1    Sep.2010     grey     grey     grey     grey     grey     grey     grey     grey     grey     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
```

If a change occurs (`change == 1`), I want the correspondent column `month.year` in which the change occurs to receive the `value` "CHANGE":

```
  id change change_date Jan.2010 Feb.2010 Mar.2010 Apr.2010 May.2010 Jun.2010 Jul.2010 Ago.2010 Sep.2010 Oct.2010 Nov.2010 Dez.2010
1 123      0        <NA>    green    green    green    green    green    green    green      red      red      red      red      red
2 124      1    May.2010    black    black      red      red   CHANGE     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
3 125      0        <NA>     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     grey
4 126      1    Sep.2010     grey     grey     grey     grey     grey     grey     grey     grey   CHANGE     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
```

The solutions I've tried failed in different ways. I appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, you can do it like this:

```r
# Work out which rows need changed, and which corresponding column
with(df,
  data.frame(
    index = which(change == 1),
    column = change_date[change == 1]
  )
) -> to_change

# Use that object to make all the changes in a loop
for(i in seq_along(to_change$index)){
  df[to_change$index[i], to_change$column[i]] = "CHANGE"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is vectorised base R way -

```
# Row numbers
row <- which(df$change == 1)
# Column numbers
col <- match(df$change_date[row], names(df))
# Create a matrix of row/column index to change the values
df[cbind(row, col)] <- "CHANGE"
df

#   id change change_date Jan.2010 Feb.2010 Mar.2010 Apr.2010 May.2010
#1 123      0        <NA>    green    green    green    green    green
#2 124      1    May.2010    black    black      red      red   CHANGE
#3 125      0        <NA>     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink
#4 126      1    Sep.2010     grey     grey     grey     grey     grey

#  Jun.2010 Jul.2010 Ago.2010 Sep.2010 Oct.2010 Nov.2010 Dez.2010
#1    green    green      red      red      red      red      red
#2     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
#3     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     pink     grey
#4     grey     grey     grey   CHANGE     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
```